# Installing TexLive 2010 in Ubuntu 10.10: problem with PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, ubuntu-10.10

I'm followint these instructions to install Kile+TexLive 2010 with package manager on my Ubuntu Maverick: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=141934

The problem I have is that when I finish downloading all the packages to my computer, I have to edit the path but Ubuntu doesn't recognize it. The lines are the following:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2005/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

`export PATH`

I run echo $PATH and as long as I don't close the terminal, the path appears with the echoing, but if I close it, the path disappears. Nevertheless (whether I close the terminal or not), I'm supposed to run texhash but I am told that the command is not found. I already tried editing the path by adding the two lines above to both .bashrc in my home directory and to bash.bashrc in /etc/ directory.

I'm just following the instructions linked above, but I'm a linux rookie. Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

in order to permanently change any environment variable under Ubuntu/Linux, you must modify the files you mentioned (for example  `~/.profile`). If you simply issue an export via the terminal, its effect will end once the terminal is closed. Sometime it is needed to perform a logout/login for the changes to take effect.
Also, mind the syntax of what you write in the above mentioned file(s), like `"`'s around `$PATH`.

Refer to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/44275/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path-in-ubuntu